Android Compose LottieAnimation: play compositions in a sequence
I am trying to get what works in LottieAnimationView, playing compositions sequentially. With this code, there is a bug where the last frame of the last composition doesn't disappear and animation leaves a trail of frames from compositions that stopped playing. Is it a problem in my code or Lottie Compose doesn't support this yet? I was hoping to update "composition" value as a mutable property but to no avail.
@Composable
fun Play(file: Int) {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
        LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(file)
    )
    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)
    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        progress = { progress }
    )
    if (progress == 1f) {
        // compute UI-blocking functions
        Play(nextFile)
    }
}

Edit:
This code leaves no trailing but the animation sequence flickers upon starting the next composition. In XML it works flawlessly.
@Composable
fun Play() {
    @Composable
    fun c1(): Pair<LottieComposition?, Float> {
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
            LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.anim1)
        )
        val p by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)
        return composition to p
    }
    @Composable
    fun c2(): Pair<LottieComposition?, Float> {
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
            LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.anim2)
        )
        val p by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)
        return composition to p
    }
    val dir = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val p = if (dir.value) c1() else c2()
    LottieAnimation(
        composition = p.first,
        progress = { p.second }
    )
    if (p.second == 1f) {
        // ui-blocking
        dir.value = !dir.value
    }
}

Edit 2: this code works better, but since the next composition starts at the same instant as the blocking functions its first frame gets stuck then jumps ahead, so the animation is not smoooth.
@Composable
fun Play() {
    val composition1 by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.anim1))
    val composition2 by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.anim2))
    val state = remember { LottieAnimatable() }
    LaunchedEffect(composition1, composition2) {
        if (composition1 == null || composition2 == null) return@LaunchedEffect
        while (<condidion>) {
            state.animate(composition1)
            state.animate(composition2)
        }
    }
    LottieAnimation(state.composition, { state.progress })
    if (state.progress == 1f) // blocking functions
}


